# syntax error android package name

Tags: android, package

I have a problem in my .java files of my android app. 
The package name at the top of the page produces an error. 
The package names are identical throughout the package, don't use capital letters, underscores or hyphens. 
I have tried different names using naming conventions, reversing the order of the words. 
The latest name which is on the screenshot is the shortest one I have tried but still I receive the same error. I have searched and searched for a remedy on forums but to no avail.

The specific error is -> error: Error parsing XML:syntax error

Does anybody know what this relates to and how to go about fixing it?!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbPrY.jpg)

Comment: you have errors in your layout fix them first.

Comment: These are the errors in my layout. Have I put the .java files in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put java files in src, in your package which is hire.link.

Layout folder is for the layout files, i.e xml files only..

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for putting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

As you have provide a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbPrY.jpg) where we can see that files in layout folder are with .java extension. It may be a reason of error. change that with .xml extension a remove any error in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the java files in src directory

Layout directory is for xml files